# error:undefined label, how to use label statement in this code in java?

Tags: java, label

I read in textbooks for Java that any statement can be labeled and can be used with break.
But while trying this code i get error undefined label. (Guys at stackoverflow wait before marking this question as duplicate, i have checked those questions but none of those explain this problem).

```
public class LabelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        first: System.out.println("First statement");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Second statement");
            break first;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JLS 14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7)

> The scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately
>   contained Statement.

So in your case, the scope of lable `first` is the `sysout` statement following the lable. To be clearer, you can define the scope using *curly braces*, and within these braces its valid to *jump to the label*. So below are valid

```
first: {
        System.out.println("First statement");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Second statement");
            break first;
        }
    }
```

OR

```
first: {
    System.out.println("First statement");
    break first;
}
second:
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    System.out.println("Second statement");
    break second;
}
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested but it still shows undefined label error.

Comment: have you added braces after the Sysout statement and have done `break first;` inside those braces?

Comment: Yes for loop should be inside the first:{}. It works fine, Curly braces was needed.

But is there a way to do this:

Comment: But is there a way to do this: exit first: label with break first; being in other loop?