# Followup on java label convention

Tags: java

My question is a followup on [error:undefined label, how to use label statement in this code in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159965/errorundefined-label-how-to-use-label-statement-in-this-code-in-java). I could not add these as comments as I have not built enough votes.

a) Why does java give an undefined label error, when the label is clearly defined in the mentioned case, i.e. why did not javac give a more understandable error like break works only with labels for blocks.

b) Why does java allow the above syntax (a label for a simple statement) when it clearly is not useful. Are there cases where the mentioned syntax is useful that I have overlooked.

Comment: I don't see why there are labels at all in java. Never needed them. a) I just assume the compiler only searches the corresponding block for the label. So the error message is correct, because in this block, the label is undefined. b) how is the compiler supposed to know what's useful? What's your suggestion? UselessLabelError?

Comment: If I move that label just before a for, do or a while anywhere in code, the break works fine, so it isn't looking for it just in the preceding block. Since the functionality is so flexible in where I can "goto", i would expect incorrect operation to be reported or disallowed.